# React Native ListView dataSource allways null

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this piece of code

```
  componentWillMount() {
    return fetch("http://10.0.3.2:8080/all", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseData => {
            this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({
                rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
            });
            this.setState({
                dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(responseData)
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("error : " + error);
        });
};
```

It brings me the data from my api, i already test it with `console.log(this.state.dataSource)` and the result was
[console.log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOm28.png)

But when i add the code

```
<ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={(rowData, navi) => this.renderEvent(rowData, this.props.nav)}
/>
```

I receive this error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dM3s.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this issue fixed by adding a simple constructor to your main component? I'd imagine you are getting this issue because you haven't received the data yet at the time of your initial render. Something like

```
class Test extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            dataSource = [];
        }
   }
```

So when you have your `ListView` , atleast it will have something to pull from initially.

Hope this helps, but if not, have a look at [this article](https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/) , explains this concept further in depth.